# Process.Start() is not working in windows 10

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-10

I am using this below code to open a browser programmatically,this is not working in windows 10 whereas it is working in all the previous versions like Windows 8.1, Windows 7, etc.

Process.Start("http://stackoverflow.com");

Is there anyway to open a browser window programmatically in windows 10?

Comment: What type of project are you building? Do you get a compiler error or a runtime error? What is the exact error you get?

Answer (score 1):

Try to open it with explorer (not internet explorer):

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("explorer.exe", "http://stackoverflow.com");
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

It probably has to do with the default browser being a modern app... it used to happen with Chrome/ModernUI when it was your default browser on Windows 8 too

Comment: I have already tried that piece of code but it is not working too..:(

Comment: i have the same issue but my app simply crashes without exceptions or error